# What determines bonus xp?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Sometimes when I kill an enemy, I get a popup saying that I received bonus experience for the kill.

[image: gw]

Why do I get this bonus XP? I can't seem to narrow it down the variables. It happens whether I'm partying or solo, and whether I'm in an event or just grinding regular mobs.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> "Bonus Experience - When you kill an enemy in the world, you might see 5 xp + 2 xp pop up . What this means is you’ll gain bonus experience depending on how long an enemy has been alive in the world, which gives you even more incentive to explore."

[Enemies that have been alive](http://www.guildwars2guru.com/topic/22266-guild-wars-2-mass-info-for-the-uninitiated/) (bear with me, that's a huge article. Somewhere halfway through) for a longer amount of time than other mobs give bonus experience based on the amount of time they've been around. This is to discourage grinding in one place.

Note: The amount of XP you receive is also respective of your level.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the difference in level? I thought you got bonus xp also by killing mobs above your level

Comment: @stoldark: You get more experience, but it's not specifically labelled as "bonus" experience I don't believe.

Comment: The article that I quoted and linked to states that the information has been obtained directly from Arena Net.

I've also gone out and tested this; mobs that have just spawned do not give any bonus experience, whereas little-explored areas have more bonus experience.

Comment: An early level 80 player mentioned she grinded on out of the way areas where mobs had 2-3k bonus experience and only 2-3 hundred regular exp. I personally have gotten 500+ bonus experience from a 100 exp enemy. therefore it seems that they is a very high cap on the amount of available bonus exp, and that it is often worth seeking out

Comment: Is it safe to say it applies to resource nodes too?

Comment: I believe resource nodes give experience based on a combination of the tier of resource and player level.